# Issue with condition in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the problem with following query.

I have four tables:

```
OBGT - T0
OACT- T1
OBGS - T2
OASC - T3
```

And my query is:

```
SELECT *FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT
    concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2])  As [AcctCode],
    T1.[AcctName],
    T2.[Name],
    concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]),T0.[DebLTotal] AS [ANNUAL BUDGET],
    (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) where T3.SegmentId = '1') AS [Project],
    (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) where T3.SegmentId = '2') AS [Distt]
FROM OBGT T0
    INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
    INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] 
    INNER JOIN OASC T3 ON (T3.SegmentId = '1' AND T3.Code = [Segment_1])
                       OR (T3.SegmentId = '2' AND T3.Code = [Segment_2])

) AS d
```

WHERE Distt = '001'
So in this query:

- OASC - T3 table have the field SegmentId which have two Id 1 and 2
- OACT - T0 table have two fields Segment_1 (values are matching with SegmentId = 1) and Segment_2 (values arematching with SegmentId = 2).

You can check in the query.

But the problem is coming if I put a condition.

`where Project = 100` is working but if the condition is `where Project = 100 and Distt = 001` then I get an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Invalid column name 'Distt'.

Comment: Show the error message please.

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'Distt'. this works for one condition at a time. not both @Jens

Comment: You can not use th alias `Distt` in a where clause. You can only use it in a having clause.

Comment: then how can i get my required result? please help out @Jens

Comment: Wrap your current query up in a derived table.

Comment: try to add `having Distt =001` to your statment

Answer (score 2):

Put you original query as a derived table:

```
select * from
(
SELECT DISTINCT
    concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2])  As 'AcctCode',
    T1.[AcctName] as dummyname1,
    T2.[Name]  as dummyname2,
    concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]) as dummyname3,
    T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET',
    (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) where T3.SegmentId = '1') AS 'Project',
    (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) where T3.SegmentId = '2') AS 'Distt'
FROM OBGT T0
INNER JOIN OACT T1
    ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
INNER JOIN OBGS T2
    ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] 
INNER JOIN OASC T3
    ON (T3.SegmentId = '1' AND T3.Code = [Segment_1])
    OR (T3.SegmentId = '2' AND T3.Code = [Segment_2])
) dt
where Project = 100 and Distt =001
```

**NOTE**: You need to add column names/aliases for each column before you can use it!

Comment: No column name was specified for column 4 of 'dt'.  I am getting this thing. which column i need to add ? @jarlh

Comment: Simply add a column alias for each selected column, just like already you do with Project and Distt. (I'll soon add dummy names in my code!)

Comment: They are there, "as dummyname1" and "as dummyname2".

Comment: I am still getting the same error near 'dt'.No column name was specified for column 4 of 'dt'

Comment: @Kira That line that ends in "ANNUAL BUDGET" actually specifies *two* columns. The first (column 4 in the select) doesn't have an alias yet - so specify it.

Comment: @hans i specified that but still.. can you show me in edits plz

Comment: @jarlh i am not getting now any data with this query. please check. error is gone now.. but no data is coming up now. please have a look.

Comment: @jarlh whenever i used where Distt = '001-Provincial' and Project = '110-Faces' then no result is coming. if i used one condition only if for Distt then Project field showing me null values and vice versa. Please help out . i could not find out how to get both conditions

Comment: @Kirat, maybe you want OR instead of AND?

Comment: @jarlh there is no difference i am getting by using OR , because concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2]) this thing should be update too if we put condition for distt and project because as  it has same value for  [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2]. please help out if you can. i tried alot but could not get required result

Comment: @jarlh will it be possible to get required result ?

Comment: Of course, nothing is impossible. But I can't see what you mean. Create a sqlfiddle and also specify it's expected result. (www.sqlfiddle.com).

Answer (score 1):

In the `SELECT` clause you have created an expression, you have then created a column alias i.e `{expression}` as `[Alias]`.

Two things, to fix your problem you should use a derived table (see below), secondly don't use single quotes for column aliases - use square brackets.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2])  As [AcctCode],
        T1.[AcctName],
        T2.[Name],
        concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]),T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET',
        (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) where T3.SegmentId = '1') AS [Project],
        (SELECT concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) where T3.SegmentId = '2') AS [Distt]
    FROM OBGT T0
        INNER JOIN OACT T1 ON T0.[AcctCode] = T1.[AcctCode]
        INNER JOIN OBGS T2 ON T0.[Instance] = T2.[AbsId] 
        INNER JOIN OASC T3 ON (T3.SegmentId = '1' AND T3.Code = [Segment_1])
                           OR (T3.SegmentId = '2' AND T3.Code = [Segment_2])

    ) AS d
WHERE Distt = 001
```

Be aware you might get another issue with your query if those sub-queries on the `SELECT` clause return more than 1 row! Your query will give another error.

Project works because it's probably a column in one of the tables.

Comment: i am getting same error No column name was specified for column 4 of 'd'. with your code too.

Comment: My bad - I didn't convert 'ANNUAL BUDGET' to [ANNUAL BUDGET]

Comment: Still same error as i written up : No column name was specified for column 4 of 'd'. @Tony

Comment: Re-post exactly how you have the query now please - ta.

Comment: i am again getting same error with this edited post Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 18
No column name was specified for column 4 of 'd'

Comment: I cannot help you further Kirat until you post exactly the query you are now executing - cheers, T

Comment: i exactly copy your query and paste it into my sql server then execute . and got this error. @Tony

Comment: I see the issue - you have two column outputs on the same line, you need to give concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]) a column alias, e.g. concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]) as X, T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET',

Comment: Tony  Please check my question query again. i put already an alias as you are saying .

Comment: No - you haven't and that is why you are getting the error, copy and paste my modified line into the query and it will work.

Comment: Just to be clearer, this is two expressions and result in two columns one aliased and one not: concat(T3.[Code],'-',T3.[Name]),T0.[DebLTotal] AS 'ANNUAL BUDGET',

Comment: yea yea.. its ok now. error is gone but now same problem as with @jarlh . no data is coming up. only name of fields are coming . :(

Comment: Run the query without the WHERE clause to see what is coming out in the Distt column. I wonder if it's because you are using a sub-query - use CASE expression instead: CASE WHEN T3.SegmentId = '2' THEN concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) ELSE NULL END AS [Distt]

Comment: Yes Tony without where clause i am getting data . but not with conditions

Comment: What values do you get for Distt?

Comment: for distt i am getting all distt values , means the values which have SegmentId =2

Comment: Basically you are checking an integer 001 against what is a string - distt looks something like x-x-x because of the string concatenation you are doing with concat(T3.Code , '-', T3.[Name]) -> that is now your problem.

Comment: okay let me do experiments..i will let you know here..Please stay tuned.. give me few time.. Thanks Tony ..:)

Comment: no, distt should be like 001, 002 . even if i update according to distt and project then all data should be updated , concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2])  This should also be updated , as i have put condition that SegmentId 1 = Segment_1 and Id 2 = Segment_2.

Comment: It's impossible for distt to be 001 because it will always have a dash in it - you will be seeing that in the results that distt always contains a dash. Why are you concatenating a dash between the two strings but expecting a result without a dash?

Comment: yes i even try with 001-abc as written in query.. but its not giving me result . when i use only one at a time. only then i can get result. but i want for both distt and project. and concat([Segment_0], '-' , [Segment_1], '-',[Segment_2]) this should be updated @Tony